# Fetch React components from server

Tags: reactjs

I am working on ReactJs for a will. I used Typescript in both client and server side for development. I used `npm run build` to build my project, I will deliver only the build folder now.

Client:

```
Client
       build
         -static
         -index.html
Server
      node_modules
      src
      package.json
      package-lock.json
      tsconfig.json
```

everything is file, For few cases I need get ReactjsComponents from server. These new Components are created by each user.

New ReactJs

```
ButtonList
      ButtonListComponent.tsx
      index.ts
      IProps.ts
```

I converted .tsx file to .js using babel

```
ButtonList
      ButtonListComponent.d.ts
      ButtonListComponent.js
      index.d.ts
      index.js
      IProps.d.ts
      IProps.js
```

And In server I rendered to plain html and sent the html as string to client and printed.

ReactHelper.ts

```
import React from 'react'
import * as  ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import ButtonList from '../../NewComponents/ButtonList'

export function ExportReactComponent(){
    var reactHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(ButtonList);
    return reactHtml
}
```

But I used functional Components and materialUI the hooks are not working. So instead of create reactComponents and converting to js. I wrote Plain html and sent to client for printing. but in those case scripts are not working.

ReactHelper.ts

```
export function ExportReactComponent(){
    var htmlInput = `<h1>The script element</h1>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
        </script> 
    `;
    return htmlInput
}
```

someone help me, if tried these things but not works as expected, is there any other good solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Git repo:  `https://github.com/nivedhauswin/ReactApp.git`

I used Iframe to display user components. I want to track location change in Iframe `contentWindow.location.href` but i get

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Comment: Could you create a reproducible demo, so that it could be easy to figure what is going wrong, maybe a repo or something?

Comment: I have added the git repo, and I used iframe for support of normal html scripts, please take a look at react scripts